# SonarQube exclude files

Tags: sonarqube, tfs-2015, sonarqube-scan

Our Build fails due to such error:

> The folder 'F:\TFS_Agents\Default_work\58\s\Sources\DotNet\foo\OnlineHelp\Syntax' does not exist...

I checked the original folder OnlineHelp, and there is no folder named Syntax inside. Instead there is an auto-generated file named

> Syntax,_functions,_currencies_and_units.html

So i suggested to exclude the whole OnlineHelp folder like this:
[exclude filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFeg1.png)

But still get the same error. Did i do any mistakes with the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild has a known limitation with files containing commas, see [SONARMSBRU-199](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-199) .

There's anyhow little value in analysing generated code (quality feedback not actionable by end-user), you're better off [excluding projects](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Excluding+Artifacts+from+the+Analysis) made of generated code.